# What is the correct way to set up a dropzone on a partial view?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, dropzone.js

I am attempting to set up a dropzone on a partial view but the init() function is never fired. I placed the exact same dropzone on the parent view and it is working correctly. What could be causing it to work correctly on the parent view but not on the child/partial view? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck for some time on this issue.

```
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
        <div class="fallback">
            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
            <input type="button" value="Upload" class="k-button" />
        </div>
    </div>


<script>

Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;

    Dropzone.options.dropzoneForm = {

        init: function () {

            alert("init");

            this.on("complete", function (data) {
                //var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');
                var res = JSON.parse(data.xhr.responseText);

                if (this.getQueuedFiles().length == 0) {
                    alert("Image was uploaded successfully."); //Success Message
                }

            });
        },

        url: '@Url.Action("SaveFormImage", "Project")' + "?projID=" + '@projectID',
        paramName: "file",
        uploadMultiple: false,
        fileSizeBase: 1024,
        parallelUploads: 1,

        maxFiles: 1,
        maxFilesize: 1000,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpeg, .pdf, .bmp, .jpg, .png",
        addRemoveLinks: false,
        createImageThumbnails: false,
        dictDefaultMessage: "Drop Image Here or Click to Upload",
        //autoProcessQueue: false,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're still looking for this but you can trigger dropzone in javascript :

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
```

or JQuery :

```
    $("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
```

Source : [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

Best regards,

Nenos